# My apache webserver is not able to connect to Cassandra nodes - what could it be?

Tags: cassandra

I have one CentOS apache server and a Cassandra cluster with three nodes.  This is an inherited environment and everything ran great for a long time, but then it came time to resize the environment.  AWS instances were stopped, started, and now the web server is not able to connect to the Cassandra cluster giving a 500 error. Instance sizes then changed back.  Now the app is down and I have no clue how to fix it =(

I think networking and IP's are good, and I can confirm port 9160 connectivity from the WWW server to all three database nodes.

I can see errors in the WWW server logs with the correct IP and port, and I can even see the connection being established.  The errors say:

```
AllServersUnavailable: An attempt was made to connect to each of the serverstwice, but none of the attempts succeeded. The last failure was TTransportException: Could not connect to 10.170.213.248:9160

AllServersUnavailable: An attempt was made to connect to each of the serverstwice, but none of the attempts succeeded. The last failure was TTransportException: Could not connect to 10.178.45.236:9160

llServersUnavailable: An attempt was made to connect to each of the serverstwice, but none of the attempts succeeded. The last failure was TTransportException: Could not connect to 10.225.197.230:9160
```

All Cassandra services are running and the cassandra.log's look happy "Now serving reads"  System log says "10.143.117.38 is now UP" for all three servers.

Here is some output of some other commands that might help:

```
sh-4.2$ nodetool info nToken            : 113427455640312821154458202477256070484 Gossip active    : true Thrift active    : true Load             : 9.39 GB Generation No    : 1611895692 Uptime (seconds) : 83201 Heap Memory (MB) : 401.85 /
3718.00 Data Center      : datacenter1 Rack             : rack1 Exceptions       : 0 Key Cache        : size 2404128 (bytes), capacity 104857584 (bytes), 2994 hits, 2995 requests, 1.000 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds Row Cache        : size 0 (bytes), capacity 0 (bytes), 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
```

sh-4.2$ nodetool version ReleaseVersion: 1.1.12

```
sh-4.2$ nodetool ring
Note: Ownership information does not include topology, please specify a keyspace.
Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token
                                                                                           168074484673131718821527957327308024233
10.95.194.242   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  6.22 GB         1.21%               0
10.7.190.37     datacenter1 rack1       Down   Normal  ?               9.39%               15973936546968416234154377765763813244
10.143.117.38   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  6.83 GB         23.94%              56713727820156410577229101238628035242
10.73.192.174   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  9.39 GB         33.33%              113427455640312821154458202477256070484
10.102.135.16   datacenter1 rack1       Down   Normal  ?               8.90%               128573185542433179728243515545762289174
10.63.154.71    datacenter1 rack1       Down   Normal  ?               4.78%               136711714759702326565809208545146576991
10.142.216.146  datacenter1 rack1       Down   Normal  ?               18.43%              168074484673131718821527957327308024233
sh-4.2$
```

If anyone has any idea what could be going on or what to try I would really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

> the Cassandra cluster giving a 500 error.

First of all, Cassandra does not and never has had a web server component.  Therefore, it cannot generate a HTTP status code (your 500 error).  That 500 error is likely coming from an app running on a web server, which is throwing a generic "server error" because the web app cannot connect to Cassandra.

Looks like what happened here, is that your three node cluster came back with new IP addresses when you restarted the nodes (I count 7 nodes above).  What you'll need to do, is to add the *new* IP addresses as connection endpoints in the web app.  Additionally, you'll need to do a `nodetool removenode` on all `DN` nodes listed above.  Otherwise your driver will still try to route requests to them.

```
$ nodetool version
ReleaseVersion: 1.1.12
```

That version of Cassandra is about a decade old.  Based on the fact that the app is connecting on port 9160, it is using a Thrift library...likely Hector or Astyanax.  Both were built for Java, and both have been deprecated for years now.  At some point, you'll want to upgrade or retire this app.

Comment: I think you're right on all counts.  The web server is throwing the 500 error because apparently it can't connect to the DB.  It looks like on this version I do not have the "removenode" command available on my version, maybe it would be nodetool decommission?

Comment: I should add - I have repointed to web server to the new nodes as well as updated cassandra.yaml to have the correct peers and listening endpoints.  I've actually had to do this before.  This cluster is built in AWS classic and not VPC, so the IP's change on reboot.  I've always been able to get it working again though, but this time I simply cannot.

Comment: Right!  I forgot.  In 1.1 it’s “removetoken”

Comment: I did the remove token for force removed all of the DN nodes......and it actually worked.  Thanks Aaron I really appreciate your time and support.